# How does go to definition work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, visual-studio-code

Im trying to create an extension that can copy a Vs code definition file path by right clicking on a word in any doc is there a way to access the file path in VS code without having to opening up the file with the go to definition?